# error in unit test vue.js karma (webpack): undefined is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner, vuejs2

I'm using the webpack template generated by Vue's CLI and have been trying to add some unit tests. And example has already been provided and it works perfectly:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'

describe('Hello.vue', () => {
  it('should render correct contents', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Hello)
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent)
      .to.equal('Welcome to Your Vue.js App')
  })
})
```

Then I try to add another test which I copied straight from Vue's documentation ([Documentation link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html)) but something weird happened:

```
// Inspect the raw component options
it('has a created hook', () => {
  console.log(typeof Hello.created)
  expect(typeof Hello.created).toBe('function')
})
```

I got the following error:

```
LOG LOG: 'function'
    ✗ has a created hook
    undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect((0, _typeof3.default)(_Hello2.default.created)).toBe('function')')
webpack:///test/unit/specs/Hello.spec.js:16:38 <- index.js:75919:64
```

So it seems like `Hello.created` gives me an `undefined`, but as you can see, I also `console.log` it to double check, and it does give it the desired result: `undefined`

Can anyone give me some help on what happened and how to fix it? I've already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786049/error-in-unit-test-vue-js-karma-undefined-is-not-a-constructor) and still couldn't make it work.

For your reference, here's how `Hello.vue` looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      message: 'hello!'
    }
  },
  created () {
    console.log('oh crap')
    this.message = 'bye!'
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the template is actually using chai instead of jasmine to do unit test.

In this case,

`expect(typeof Hello.created).to.equal('function')`

or

`expect(Hello.created).to.be.a('function')`

both work.

Answer (score 0):

For me **to.be** or **toBe** did not work. Instead I used **.equal** in the following way (to get the return of a component method) :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SingleTask from '@/components/SingleTask'

describe('SingleTask.vue', () => {
   it('should return true', () => {
     const Constructor = Vue.extend(SingleTask)
     const vm = new Constructor().$mount()

     expect(vm.forUnitTest()).equal(true);
   })
})
```

That's what worked for me